# One-way anova of treatment and response, not receiving p values and F statistics

Tags: r, missing-data, anova, p-value

My data are responses to the development of sporophytes to a certain treatment. Per treatment, there are 5 replicates.

[image: Showing rows and columns for the start, values are present]

The data goes on like above until B-HN-18-5 (Bodø, high nutrient, 18C, replicate 5)for the temperature 4, 8, 12, and 18. However, I am only using sporophytes per cm2 and the treatment columns.

My response variable is how many sporophytes developed but I want to examine if the relationship between the treatment and the response is significant or not in R.

I typed:

```
Anova1 <- aov(sporophytes.cm2~Treatment, SelectData1)
summary(Anova1)
```

my results did not show the F Statistics and p-value of the response:

```
summary(Anova1)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Treatment   39   1531   39.25
```

How can I obtain these?

Comment: Hi, could you provide us a minimal example of your data ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, certainly! Thanks for the reply, can you see some of the data now?
I am new to stack overflow, so my experience is not the best.

Comment: Please post your data as **text** rather than as a screenshot; it's much more convenient and accessible that way.